# catkin build configuration options

Tags: catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to define the default behaviour of `catkin_make` with a .cmake-file or such?

For example, I would need to disable some platform-specific ROS-packages included in a repository. Or, toggle CUDA or some other optional library. The problem I'm facing is that catkin includes all subdirectories in the workspace, so I can't make my own CMake macro which would set(ENABLE_CUDA) or set(BUILD_ANALYSIS_TOOLS), and then add_subdirectory() if this is set.

To give some idea what would be nice to have, OpenCV does its build options very nicely (from line 155):
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221921/catkin-build-configuration-options/) by [Tommi](https://answers.ros.org/users/23616/tommi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2015-12-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OpenCV is a single project so it's not really comparable to a system which builds groups of projects. You can certainly add options to individual CMake projects, but you'd have to pass options to each of them.

As for controlling which packages get built in a catkin workspace, you can use `CATKIN_IGNORE` files to prevent certain packages from getting processed by `catkin_make`. Or you can use the `CATKIN_BLACKLIST_PACKAGES` variable to blacklist certain packages, see: http://answers.ros.org/question/54181/how-to-exclude-one-package-from-the-catkin_make-build/

You get more control with the upcoming tools provided by the `catkin_tools` project, but it's got some problems that we're still working out before it's ready for prime time:

- http://lists.ros.org/lurker/message/20151110.195101.767ad75f.en.html
- https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools/issues/90

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1